# Android and C++ socket communication over WiFi Direct

Tags: android, c++, sockets, raspberry-pi, wifi-direct

**Overview:** I'm currently working on an Android app which connects to a Linux system via WiFi Direct, with the final intent of streaming video over this established connection.

The raspi will be acting as a server in this scenario, with the Android being the client. I will be streaming from a camera attached to the pi, and receiving this video on the Android side to display in my app using ExoPlayer. The pi cannot start sending this video over a datagram socket without having the client's ip address. The Android device will also need to send out miscellaneous packets to the Pi which would be telling it what to do, thus the need for both devices having each others ip addresses.

The current Linux system I am working on is a Raspberry Pi running Raspian, with development taking place in C++. The Android runtime environment being a Samsung Galaxy Tab A.

**Problem:** I'm able to successfully establish a connection between the two devices, which I have setup so that the Raspberry Pi is always the group owner. With the Pi being group owner, it doesn't have immediate access to the Android's IP address; thus a temporary TCP socket connection must be made between the two so the Raspberry Pi can take note of the Android's IP address.

After a WiFi connection is established, this C++ code is ran on the Pi to open & accept a TCP socket connection from the Android:

```
#include<cstddef>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/un.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

#define BACKLOG 2 //Allowed connection count.

#define PORT 8988 //The port we will be listening on.

//The static IP of p2p-dev-wlan0
const std::string MY_IP = "192.168.4.1";

bool listen_for_ip() {

    //Buffer for receiving messages.
    char buffer[256];

    //Create Server Socket:
    int sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock_fd < 0)
        return false;
    else
        std::cout << "Created Server" << std::endl;

    struct sockaddr_in my_addr, peer_addr;

    //Recieve messages from IPv4 addresses.
    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    //Set our IP address of the socket to the value in "MY_IP"
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(MY_IP.c_str());
    //my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // Also tested with this, no luck.

    //Set our in port to the value in "PORT"
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    //Attempt to bind to IP and port.
    if (bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) == 0)
        std::cout << "Binded successfully" << std::endl;
    else
        return false;

    //Listen on the socket
    if (listen(sock_fd, BACKLOG) < 0)
        return false;

    //Accept a connection.
    socklen_t peer_addr_size = sizeof(peer_addr);
    std::cout << "Accepting connection ..." << std::endl;
    int new_fd = accept(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &peer_addr, &peer_addr_size);
    if (new_fd == -1) {
        std::cout << "Error accepting connect" << std::endl;
        close(sock_fd);
        return false;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Connection accept completed status = " << new_fd << std::endl;

    //
    char ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(peer_addr.sin_addr), ip, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    if (recv(new_fd, buffer, 256, 0) < 0) {
        close(new_fd);
        close(sock_fd);
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "Client says " << buffer << std::endl;

    //Do other stuff with connection ...

    close(new_fd);
    close(sock_fd);
    return true;
}
```

This code runs successfully, and as should blocks on the accept() call to wait for the Android connect to the socket.

On the Android side this code is ran to connect to the Pi (Group owner) over a basic socket:

```java
public static final int PORT = 8988;

private static final int TIMEOUT_MS = 10000;

private final String myIp;

private WifiP2pInfo mGroupInfo;

private final WifiDirectService mWifiDirectService;

public P2pClientSocket(WifiDirectService wifiDirectService, WifiP2pInfo groupInfo, String ourDeviceIP) {
    mGroupInfo = groupInfo;
    myIp = ourDeviceIP;
    mWifiDirectService = wifiDirectService;
    exchangeIP();
}

/**
 * Utilizes a basic socket & TCP to ensure that the IP address of this machine is sent to the group owner of established P2P group.
 * If there is an error with sending or writing this message, or the message times out,
 * {@link WifiDirectService} will be notified to immediately dispose of its current connection.
 */
private void exchangeIP()  {
    Socket initSocket = new Socket();
    Runnable r = () -> {
        try {
            String host = mGroupInfo.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress();
            Log.d(TAG, "Opening socket to : " + host + ", " + PORT);
            initSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, PORT), TIMEOUT_MS);
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(initSocket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStreamWriter.write(myIp, 0, myIp.length());
            outputStreamWriter.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "Successfully wrote IP.");
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            String message = "Connection Timeout - Disconnecting.";
            Log.e(TAG, message, e);
            mWifiDirectService.socketError(message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String message = "IP Exchange Error - Disconnecting.";
            Log.e(TAG, message, e);
            mWifiDirectService.socketError(message);
        } finally {
            try {
                initSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Error Closing Init Socket.");
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(r).start();
}
```

The value of
`String host = mGroupInfo.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress()`
will always be the IP address of the raspberry pi. I have configured it so it runs as a DHCP server with a static IP using:

```
cat > /etc/systemd/network/12-p2p-wlan0.network <<EOF 
[Match] 
Name=p2p-wlan0-* 
[Network] 
Address=192.168.4.1/24 
DHCPServer=yes 

EOF
```

However, on the .connect() call, the timeout threshold is always reached. I'm a bit of a networking noob so I'm not entirely sure on what I'm doing wrong. Included is the timeout stack trace:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.4.1 (port 8988) from /192.168.4.163 (port 33122) after 10000ms
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:191)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:135)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
        at com.nlos.networking.P2pClientSocket.lambda$exchangeIP$0$P2pClientSocket(P2pClientSocket.java:54)
        at com.nlos.networking.-$$Lambda$P2pClientSocket$fxU2Z0Zg0gRF1Fyl1fNnqgO2m8I.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

I've tried multiple different sockets, ensured that the pi is actually up and listening, and am honestly stumped at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `With the Pi being group owner, it doesn't have immediate access to the Android's IP address; thus a temporary TCP socket connection must be made between the two so the Raspberry Pi can take note of the Android's IP address.` Why would the raspi have to know the ip of your Android device? Could you tell where it us needed for? And which device would be the server? And where would the client run?

Comment: `I'm able to successfully establish a connection between the two devices, ` Yes that wifi direct connection is a matter of the operating systems of the two devices. But after that a client application should try to connect with a listening server application. You did not ever talk about client or server. And only a client needs to know an ip.

Comment: `String host = mGroupInfo.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress()` Please tell the value of host.

Comment: @blackapps Sorry for not establishing this sooner. The raspi will be acting as a server in this scenario, with the Android being the client. I will be streaming from a camera attached to the pi, and receiving this video on the Android side to display in my app using ExoPlayer. The pi cannot start sending this video over a datagram socket without having the client's ip address. The Android device will also need to send out miscellaneous packets to the Pi which would be telling it what to do, thus the need for both devices having each others ip addresses.

Comment: @blackapps The value of `String host = mGroupInfo.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress()` will always be the IP address of the raspberry pi. I have configured it so it runs as a DHCP server with a static IP using:
`cat > /etc/systemd/network/12-p2p-wlan0.network <<EOF 
[Match] 
Name=p2p-wlan0-* 
[Network] 
Address=192.168.4.1/24 
DHCPServer=yes 

EOF`

Comment: Please edit your post. Dont use comments to explain as we like to read one post that covers all. At the moment i cannot follow you switching between post and comments.

Comment: `const std::string MY_IP = "192.168.4.1";` Aha! A server does not need to know its ip address. And you should certainly not bind a server socket to any address. And if you have to bind then bind to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: @blackapps Just edited. Ah, interesting! So, instead of specifying: `my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(MY_IP.c_str());`, I can use INADDR_ANY for the value of s_addr; indicating this server socket should be listening for any input on the port set by `my_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT)`?